# nodeJS insert data from file

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, insert

I am trying to insert the data into MongoDB.

when I declare the array locally it works.

```
var data = [{Name : "Steven", Age: 44},{Name : "John", Age: 54}]
```

but when I store this file into `data.json` and read this file. I can not insert.

I got this error :

> MongoError: docs parameter must be an array of documents

```
app.get("/insert", function(request, response) {
  fs.readFile(reqPath , 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    //Handle Error
   if(!err) {
     //Handle Success   
      console.log(data); 
     db.collection("TheData").insertMany(data, function(err, r) { console.error(err);});
     //console.log("after" +defaultUsers); 
    }else {
       //Handle Error
       console.error(err);
    }
  }) 
});
```

even though, the output of data is the same as if I declare it above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type of data in this callback `fs.readFile(reqPath , 'utf8', function (err, data)` is String. you should convert your out put to json.

Of course you need to change the way the array is written to the file as well. And use double quotes for the keys

**data.json**:

```
[{"Name" : "Steven", "Age": 44},{"Name" : "John","Age": 54}]
```

**update your code**

```
app.get("/insert", function (request, response) {
  fs.readFile(reqPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    //Handle Error
    if (!err) {
      //Handle Success   
      console.log(data);
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      db.collection("TheData").insertMany(data, function (err, r) { console.error(err); });
      //console.log("after" +defaultUsers); 
    } else {
      //Handle Error
      console.error(err);
    }
  })
});
```